# Split String using split method

Tags: java

I have one String text that i would like to split,result i want to get is that when i take text/split output each part like for example: Name: John, Last Name: Davidson, Date of Birth: 05051968, Place of Birth: London. But i am not getting correct result. my code is following:

```
public class Person{
    public String name;
    public String lastName;
    public String dateOfBirth;
    public String placeOfBirth;

poblic void printDetails(){
    String text = "John.Davidson/0505168/London Micheal.Bartson/06061680/Paris";

    String[] newText = text.split("[./ ]");
    for(int i=0; i<newText.length; i++){
         String name = newText[i].split("")[0];
         String lastName = newText[i].split("")[0];
         String dateOfBirth = newText[i].split("")[0];
         String placeOfBirth = newText[i].split("")[0];
         System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", last name: " + lastName + ", date of birth: " + dateOfBirth + ", place of birth: " + placeOfBirth);
   }
```

Result i am getting is following:
       Name: J, last Name: J, date of birth: J, place of birth: J
       Name: D, last name: D, date of birth: D, place of birth: D .......
and it goes like that for every first character in text. Please can some one look and tell me where i am mistaking?

Answer (score 2):

The results of the split come in groups of four, so you need to set the step of your loop at 4, and get the individual parts through offsets 0, 1, 2, and 3, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<newText.length; i+=4){
    String name = newText[i];
    String lastName = newText[i+1];
    String dateOfBirth = newText[i+2];
    String placeOfBirth = newText[i+3];
    System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", last name: " + lastName + ", date of birth: " + dateOfBirth + ", place of birth: " + placeOfBirth);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/HL7DAn)

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight, this gave me result i want it

Comment: @Ronin You are welcome! If this works for you, consider accepting the answer to indicate that you have found a solution to your problem.

Comment: May I ask you something else, let say I want to form date in different format using LocalDate method to let say 05 May 1989, I have try to include in for loop but it is giving me exception when i do that (LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateOfBirth, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy"));

Comment: @Ronin You should ask this as a separate question - perhaps someone with good knowledge of `DateTimeFormatter` would come up with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting using the "" which means split every character. Then you take the first character. I don't know why you're doing it that way.

In summary, what happens in every loop is it takes the first character ([0]) of element i of the array, then sets every single value that wil lbe printed in the string to that character. Instead, try this

```
String[] newText = text.split("[./ ]");
for(int i = 0; i < newText.length - 4; i+=4){
    System.out.println("Name: " + newText[i] + ", last name: " + newText[i+1] + ", date of birth: " + newText[i+2] + ", place of birth: " + newText[i+3]);
}
```

However, this is a terrible solution, it relies on fixed sized entries and should not be used in practice. What if someone enters the string in a different order, or with one too many inputs or one too few? Try using more flexible designs, such as the usage of a csv format parser, so you always split using commas, and the rows can be something like

```
entry-type, entry
entry-type, entry2
entry-type, entry3
```

Or something like that. Try it out. Always try to aim for flexible solutions that don't rely on exact input to work, otherwise you will have exceptions and runtime issues like there's no tomorrow.

PS the point of the split() method is to split the string between occurences of the specified input, i.e. [./], so don't use it if you want to just give a "", that's no different than making a charArray (except instead of char[] it is String[])

Comment: I forgot to format the proposed solution for multiple names, but the concept remains the same, use an 
    for(int i = 0; i < newText.length; i+= 4){
       System.out.println("name" + newText[i] + "last name" + newText[i+1].......

Comment: Please add that comment into your answer by editing it.